# Invertible elements of $K[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ when $p(x)$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> I want to find the inverse of $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ in $L=K[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ when $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ with degree $3$.

I know elements of $L$ are like $f(x)$ such that $a,b,c$ are in $K$. I'm choosing element $g(x)=a'x^{2}+b'x+c'$ in $L$ and seting, $f(x)g(x)=1$
and know $c'$ is inverse of $c$,
but finding $a'$ and $b'$ not simple because I think finding these depend on knowing $p(x)$!
Namely, $f(x)g(x)$ must compute $(\!\!\!\mod\!\! p(x))$ to place $x^{4}$ and $x^{3}$ with power less than these.

Please help me to find $g(x)$.
Thank you.

Comment: Please use MathJaX to typeset equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ok, Thank you for edit my quastion.

Comment: You correctly noticed that the inverse will be a polynomial of degree at most 2 in $x$. But consider this: assuming $a\neq0$, if $g$ is of degree two, then fg is of degree 4, so mod $p$ it is of degree 1, so it can't be 1. So the degree of $g$ is at most 1. And the case $a=0$ is easier anyway.

Comment: A general formula in terms of $a, b, c$ and $p(x) $ would be cumbersome. A simple approach is to use the Euclidean algorithm for GCD of $f(x), p(x) $ to get polynomials $a(x), b(x) $ with $a(x) f(x) +b(x) p(x) =1$. Then $a(x) $ is inverse of $f(x) $.

Comment: but p(x) is unknown and can't calculete gcd.

Comment: @Fati: your problem should specify $K, f, p$ explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I know! But my teacher doesn't know. ;)

Comment: Then you can just describe the procedure to find the inverse (something like my comments with more explanation). Or perhaps ask your teacher about the desired form of answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ can not solving this problem; and note, degree of $g(x)$ can be $2$. for example, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $p(x)=x^{3}-2x-2$ and $f(x)=x^{2}+x+1$ then $g(x)=-\dfrac{2}{3}x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}x+\dfrac{5}{3}$ such that $fg=1$ in $K[x]/\langle‎p(x)\rangle‎$.